# Qual a importância de ter certificação?

Tags: certificado-digital

Tenho alguns amigos que tem certificações em determinadas tecnologias(Microsoft, Oracle, etc), mas se você propor um desafio usando as tecnologias que supostamente eles tem conhecimento não conseguem desenvolver, no entanto conheço pessoas que não tem certificado algum e conseguem naturalmente resolver esse desafio.

O que estou tentando dizer é que: Qual o peso de uma certificação X conhecimento técnico e prático?

Muitas pessoas quando vão prestar alguma prova de certificado **decoram** as perguntas e respostas, pois sabem que as provas são desatualizadas.

Como avaliar uma pessoa e qual o grau de conhecimento que ela tem de determinado assunto? Existem metodologias estabelecidas para isso? Para as empresas, o que isso afeta?

Comment: Essa pergunta é obviamente opinativa e ainda induz as respostas. A Certificação é um diferencial, prova que você gastou tempo se preparando e é focado. O objetivo da certificação não é compensar por anos de experiência, é completar esse experiência. Boas certificações entram em detalhes técnicos que muitas vezes passam desapercebidos para alguém com anos de experiência; você tem que estudar especificamente para aquela certificação. A certificação enriquece, como uma boa graduação ou pós. Certificação não é indicativo de experiência, e experiência não substitui a certificação. Tenha os dois.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Valor do certificado:

- No mercado: **pode ajudar numa seleção de currículo por um RH**, mas **praticamente nada** no crivo técnico.
- Para quem tirou decorando as respostas daqueles sites que as vendem: **auto-enganação**.
- Para quem se esforçou para tirar: **aprofundamento num conhecimento específico**.
- Na prática: **pouquíssima importância** se você é capaz de estudar por conta, **um pouco mais importante** se você precisa de um processo para ter disciplina de estudo.

Dica para autodidatas:

- É mais barato comprovar o conhecimento participando de um projeto *open source* ou criando projetos pessoais no GitHub, por exemplo
- É mais barato e mais produtivo comprar bons livros sobre o tema da certificação

Comment: Sobre a "auto-enganação" das empresas que requerem e das pessoas que gastam dinheiro: bem lembrado! Há que se ficar atento ao contexto e à idoneidade do certificador.  Sobre o uso do OpenSource: faltam as empresas aceitarem e colaborarem (estimulando seus funcionários) no uso de modulos ou softwares openSource... O programador que "esconde" a sua produção (a maior parte de nós analistas brasileiros!!) não está sendo pago para "esconder", deveria cobrar mais, ou exigir direito de publicar o que foi desenvolvido...

Comment: @PeterKrauss Boas observações. Eu cansei de "esconder" meu trabalho, inclusive estive concluindo um [artigo no meu blog](http://luizricardo.eti.br/2014/02/resultados-de-um-experimento-social/) sobre isso.

Answer (score 4):

Um certificado é (para o mercado) uma forma de comprovar que você tem determinado conhecimento, ao invés de impor ao contratante o ônus de descobrir e verificar isso. Naturalmente há esses pontos fora da curva, mas normalmente os profissionais certificados que conheço são dotados de conhecimento muito acima da média.

Sobre experiência, concordo que ela é **muito** mais importante que qualquer papel, mas passamos hoje por uma uniformização da nossa área, já que tanta gente de fora (em cargos de gestão, RH...) precisa lidar com profissionais de TI. Nada mais comum que criar regras que facilitem esse trabalho.

Comment: No caso de licitações empresas que tem funcionários com certificação tem preferencia, correto? Pois teoricamente os funcionários daquela empresa dominam melhor a tecnologia que o cliente precisa

Comment: @Laerte verdade, mas acontecem discrepâncias também. Minha empresa já usou minha certificação para ganhar licitações para empresas às quais eu não prestaria serviço.

Answer (score 0):

Além do que já foi dito, de que em empresas de grande porte, que precisam avaliar centenas de currículos e o certificado é utilizado como um critério de corte (preciso ou não), eu imagino que em outros casos, por menor peso que alguém, ou empresa, possa atribuir para a certificação, ela entrará sempre como um ponto positivo no seu currículo.

Digamos que apenas 2 candidatos estejam disputando uma vaga em uma empresa, por mais pessoal que seja avaliação, em casos em que os avaliadores considerarem que ambos candidatos são equivalentes, a certificação poderá ser decisiva.